# Border image on UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

I want to have a `UIView` subclass that has a border image, but I don't want or care about this 'new' frame/bounds around the border image itself.

What I wanted to do was just use `drawRect` and draw outside of the rect but all drawing is clipped and I don't see a way to not clip drawing outside of this context rect.

So now I have added a sublayer to the views layer, set `[self clipsToBounds]` on the view and override `setFrame` to control my sublayers frame and always keep it at the proper size (spilling over the views frame by 40px).

The problem with this is that `setFrame` on a `uiview` by default has no animation but `seTFrame` on a `calayer` does.

I cant just disable the animations on the `calayers` `setFrame` because if I were to call `setFrame` on the `uiview` inside a `uiview` animation block the `calayer` would still have its animation disabled.

The obvious solution is to look up the current `animationDuration` on the `uiview` animation and set a matching animation on the sublayer, but I don't know if this value is available. And even if it is, I'm afraid that calling an animation from within another animation is wrong.

Unfortunately the best solution is to not use a `calayer` at all and just add a `uiview` as a `subview` and draw into that just like I am drawing into my layer, and hope that with `autoresizingMask` set to height and width that everything will 'just work'. Just seems like unnecessary overhead for such a simple task.

Comment: actually either way it will take more glue code to preserve the capped images from being distorted while in mid animation :/

Comment: If you have got your answer please mark it as answered It give motivation to people who help you, you can also upvote them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to override the initWithFrame: to add the surrounding border pixels and contain the content in a subview. It probably is unneccesary overhead but definietly the "cocoa" route. It's probably going to be easier in the end too since a subview structure will allow you to edit the content seperatly from the border so you dont have to redraw the border when you redraw the content. And keeping them seperate simply makes sense from a OOP perspective.

The clipsToBounds route is probably the easiest route besides the subview structure but managing the border and content in one drawing cycle and in one object will probably be a lot more work so it'll be worth the overhead.

Excuse any typos, typed this from my iPhone.

Comment: ok yea i just made a uiimageview subview and gave it my capped image and override setFrame on host view and its all good now.

please hit me next time i want to 'optimize' something. :D